# Unhide CSS Div upon user login

Tags: html, css, authentication

I am trying to create a login page but am having a problem...

register.html code :

```
<a href="login.html">Login</a>
```

login.html code :

```
<div id="loginmodal" style="display:none;">
    <h1>User Login</h1>
    <form id="loginform" name="loginform" method="post" action="index.html">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="txtfield" tabindex="1">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="txtfield" tabindex="2">

        <div class="center">
            <input type="submit" name="loginbtn" id="loginbtn" class="flatbtn-blu hidemodal" value="Log In" tabindex="3">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

After clicking on Login on register.html i want `loginmodal` on login.html to `display: all;` as apposed to `display:none;`

how do I go about doing this?

Comment: From what I can work out from my edit is that he wants the loginmodal div to display when someone logs in..

Comment: Rolled back your edit because I believe there are other logical interpretations and we risk losing what the asker actually wanted. You could imagine, for example, that he wants to bring up a modal dialog when the "Login" button is clicked.

Comment: you may be looking for simple show and hide login form which can be achieved in better way with help of jQuery 

http://www.9lessons.info/2009/12/twitter-like-login-with-jquery-and-css.html

Comment: Rereading my comment I realize we had the same interpretation. I still believe the original edit was too radical, however. (I tried to reject it as such but somebody seems to be trivially approving edits right now, as you can see from the many edits on this post..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) give an `id` or `class` for the `<a>` tag

2) in css set the div loginmodal to `display:none`

3)in jquery `on click` of the anchor tag, show loginmodal

html:

```
<a id="login-link" href="login.html">Login</a>


 <div id="loginmodal">
  <h1>User Login</h1>
<form id="loginform" name="loginform" method="post" action="index.html">
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="txtfield" tabindex="1">
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="txtfield" tabindex="2">

  <div class="center"><input type="submit" name="loginbtn" id="loginbtn" class="flatbtn-blu hidemodal" value="Log In" tabindex="3"></div>
</form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#loginmodal{display:none;}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#login-link').click(function(){
$("#loginmodal").show();
});
```

Comment: +1 for a good solution but -1 for using jQuery, which was not mentioned by the asker. Far too many answers around here depend on jQuery.